# Ajax call to database not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax

in my application I have to make an ajax call to php file.it works proper in all devices. but when I tried it on ipad mini it not calls the php, so that the functionality not works, I've seen so many question about this problem and edited my code like this.

> jQuery.ajax({
>                     type: "POST",
>
> ```
>               async: true,
>               cache: false,
>               url: "directory/phpfile.php",
>               data: data,
>               success: function(response) {
>
>               }
>             });
> ```

my old code is

> jQuery.ajax({
>                   type: "POST",
>
> ```
>               url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
>
>               data: data,
>               success: function(response) {
>
>               }
>             });
> ```

and the problem still cant resolve . so please any one tell me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code

```
 $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
$.ajax(
{
    url : formURL,
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
        //data: return data from server
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
        //if fails      
    }
});
e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});

$("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit  the FORM
```

Comment: can you write my code in this format ?, actually there is no form, this function is called on button click.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>   

$(document).ready(function startAjax() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: "name=name&location=location",
    success: function(msg){
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
  });
});
```